# How do you apply a sass theme to a custom child component in angular?

Tags: angular, sass

I know there are doc pages on this, I've read them all, I've looked at probably a dozen examples and I'm somehow still confused. Would someone be able to help me understand the bare bones structure (including @import statements) of declaring a sass theme, and then using that sass theme in an encapsulated custom child component?